# Fallout 4 Artillery Map?

Tags: fallout-4

So I've been trying to build up every settlement location I can to maximize artillery coverage. I have them all owned except Boston Airport, Bunker Hill, and Covenant. I have everything linked to Red Rocket by trade routes, but haven't quite finished the artillery, turns out these settlers want "food" and "water" and "shelter" instead.

But after I get all the artillery set up, what areas are left uncovered? I assume the Glowing Sea is out of range, but I'd like a more precise answer. Also, if one settlement has more than 1 artillery, or if my target is in range of multiple settlements, do I get more strikes on my target? I already know that I can't target more than one spot at a time, no matter how many guns in range.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Redditor RandomVigilante made a nice (if possibly not 100% accurate) map of coverage.
[image: Artillery Coverage]

You might want to check out the full [Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3w27mo/i_made_a_map_that_shows_where_minutemen_ground/) for more information on this map (including flaws, and possibly a Red/Green Colorblind friendly version).

Comment: Great find, exactly what I have been looking for as well

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Diamond City (Home Plate) location can't actually have artillery built in it but IS listed on that map... there might be another issue or two so certainly worth checking out the full thread....

Comment: I tried to clean up the image [here](http://i.imgur.com/8ntpVCd.jpg). No more of those red/orange overlaps, now it's bright white circles. The areas in red are what's out of range.

Comment: Damn, looks like I forgot Coastal Cottage, will try again later.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one with coverage from 11 settlements [source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjer1ejl1il5s6o/Fallout-4-Map-Artillery.png?dl=0):

[image: Artillery Map]

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've embedded your image into your post for you, which you can do by clicking the image button when creating or editing a post on our site. There a few benefits to this. First, it'll host it on imgur, so it's less likely to become a deadlink in the future like a Dropbox link is. Second, having the image embedded in the post makes accessing the information a lot quicker (aka users just see it here, they don't need to navigate away).

Comment: Cheers!

I have a Photoshop editable PDF also, which has layers for all of the settlement coverage which can be turned on and off to customise your own map if anyone is interested?