# How do I call for Minutemen in Far Harbor?

Tags: fallout-4

There was an attack on the Dalton Farm settlement and I shot up a flare. It didn't say that no Minutemen could respond, but none came. Is there any way to call for Minutemen in Far Harbor?

Comment: [Fallout 4 Artillery Map?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254717/fallout-4-artillery-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flare gun is useless in the Far Harbor DLC, as the Minutemen will not respond if you use it in Maine. From the [wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Flare_gun_(Fallout_4)):

> The flare gun serves very little function on The Island, as the Minutemen have no jurisdiction there, and can't be used in that area to summon reinforcements.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be setting up a strong settlement, or settlements. Also probably making sure you have the mortar cannons at your settlement? i know they will randomly wonder to your settlements throughout the common wealth as ive seen them do many times but ive yet to really work on building settlements out in far harbor. It seems when i see minutemen walking through my settlement they were already pretty set up so maybe they tend to be attracted to your settlements when they are better established? or maybe a minuteman flag is a key to this as well? i usually have flags of them at my settlements that i see them at so maybe this contributes.